# Illegal Instruction in docker container only when built on a different host

Tags: docker, illegal-instruction, annoy

I have a docker image that is built on one of two machines in CI (call them "A" and "B") which uses the python package [trimap](https://pypi.org/project/trimap/), which uses [annoy](https://pypi.org/project/annoy/) under the hood.

The test stage in CI is then run using the built container on one of those machines separately (so build on "A" -> run on "B", or any combination thereof are possible).

The problem arises when running `docker build` on machine "A" and then running the test in the built container on machine "B", which causes [this Illegal Instruction issue](https://github.com/spotify/annoy/issues/506) ([also relevant](https://github.com/spotify/annoy/issues/513)). Running `docker build` as well as the tests on machine "B" works, and going from `build` on "B" and running tests on "A" is also OK.

I'm building `annoy` from source when I build the docker image (it's one of the recommended fixes), my current hypothesis is that it's compiling against a certain CPU instruction that is missing on the other host. Could this be true? I would have assumed that docker abstracts this away in order to maintain interoperability.